# numeric and date fields highlighting in elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch, full-text-search, highlighting

hope I could get a solution to this classical problem.

Is there any way that I could index or query elastic search numeric and date types to be searched and highlighted. The data gets searched, but cannot be highlighted. I have seen lot jiras raised in git hub on the same, but without any solution

My requirement is, I should be able to search, highlight and perform range and aggregation operation on the same. Could it be resolved using anything like "multi_filed" or "fields"(replaces multi_field as its deprecated in elastic search 2.x version).

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think it's possible to highlight for dates and numerics. Highlighting works by searching (and highlighting) a specific text, while for numeric ranges, there is no such thing. There is a range of numbers, which one to highlight? All of them? For dates, at least, this could be a very **wide** range. If something like this would be possible in Lucene, I recon it will use a lot of memory and resources to do the highlighting. As such, this is not supported.

Comment: how about indexing number field as multi_field as you answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36715688/indexing-numeric-field-as-both-int-and-string-in-elastic-search.     and performing ranges on int type and search on string type. could that be queried with a single field name for int and String?

Comment: I tested that and, unless you use a query for text search (no ranges), it won't work.

Comment: so for example, if I have a field "id" mapped as String and int. I will perform text search on "id" and if I need range operations on "Id" go for range searches. so both can be executed on same field name "id"?

Comment: No. The text query (a match for example) needs to be executed on the string subfield, range on the numeric part, as shown in my answer to your other post.

Comment: thank you so much Stefan..that helped a lot